# Factorization of $\left( \begin{array}{cc} A+D&\vec x \\ \vec y^T& a \\ \end{array} \right)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ matrix, $\vec x,\ \vec y$ be two vectors of dimension $=n-1$, $a$ be a real number. Let $D$ a $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ diagonal matrix. From which, matrix
$$\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
     A+D&\vec x  \\
     \vec y^T& a \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$
is a $n\times n$ square matrix. Decompose this matrix into a product of two block matrices. A matrix should contain, among others, only $A$, the other must contain only $D$. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Is there any relation between vectors $x,y$ and matrices (e.g. $x=Ab$ for some vector $b$)?

Comment: @MicheleV. No. They are generics.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other must contain only $D$"? Even block matrix involving D, identity, x, and a constant is not allowed?

Comment: @chhro. I mean that the matrix must be rewritten as a product of two matrices, which we call $T, U$. $T$ may contain A but not D; $U$ may contain D but not A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $0_{m,n}$ the $m$-by-$n$ zero matrix and by $I_k$ the $k$-by-$k$ identity matrix.

Let $T=\begin{bmatrix} A& I_{n-1}& 0_{n-1,1}\\ y^T& 0_{1,n-1}&a\end{bmatrix}$, and let $U=\begin{bmatrix} I_{n-1}& 0_{n-1,1}\\ D& x\\ 0_{1,n-1}& 1\end{bmatrix}$. The matrix $T$ is $n$-by-$(2n-1)$ while $U$ is $(2n-1)$-by-$n$. The product $TU$ is $n$-by-$n$, and one checks equality to the desired matrix.